# How to customize system tray icons in Lubuntu 20.04?

Tags: lubuntu, icons, 20.04, system-tray

The system tray in Lubuntu 20.04 includes the icons for Qlipper and Notification. I'd like to keep them running but hidden from the system tray. I believe there is a config file somewhere to control that, but I couldn't find it. And it's not mentioned in the Lubuntu Manual. The forum posts that I've found about system tray are all about other versions of ubuntu, and are not very applicable to Lubuntu 20.04.

may I ask if there's a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!